# UIButton touchDragInside does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button which I want to move each time I try to drag, and then move a segue each time I tap. For drag I have put that method:

```
skillsButtonReal.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.wasDragged(_:event:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)

func wasDragged (buttn : UIButton, event :UIEvent)
{

    let buttonView = buttn as UIView;
    let touches : Set<UITouch> = event.touchesForView(buttonView)!
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.locationInView(buttonView)

    let previousLocation : CGPoint = touch .previousLocationInView(buttonView)
    let delta_x :CGFloat = location.x - previousLocation.x
    let delta_y :CGFloat = location.y - previousLocation.y
    buttn.center = CGPointMake(buttn.center.x + delta_x,
                               buttn.center.y + delta_y);

}
```

Which is being called but it does not move. What else do I need to put or invoke?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be useful to you:

```
var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("recognizePanGesture:"))
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
buttonView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

```
func recognizePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
  var translate = sender.translationInView(self.view)
  sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x:sender.view!.center.x + translate.x,
  y:sender.view!.center.y + translate.y)
  sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but now I have 2 problems. First, one is that the button does not drag (I'm supposed to attach the first part on the view did load with the correct button and the second in a method), and the other problem is that the button does not segue to the next VC. What am i doing wrong there?

Comment: This answer is legitimate, but he is asking about "Touch Drag Inside", which is a real event that works with UIButtons...

Comment: Is there something else I can do?